# CMake to produce -L<path> -l<lib> link flags for static libraries

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm using CMake 2.8 in order to build an application based on MQX OS (using CodeWarrior).
The CMake project basically builds a set of static libraries (let's say LIB1 and LIB2).
I then reference these libraries in the final executable cmake rule:

```
target_add_executable(X ${some_sources})
target_link_libraries(X LIB1 LIB2)
```

My problem is that some symbols are defined in more that one library.
Thus, a link command like:

```
mwldarm <args> -o <output> <objects> /path/to1/libLIB1.a /path/to2/libLIB2.a
```

would lead to multiple definition of symbols error.
Instead, I would like CMake to generate a link command like:

```
mwldarm <args> -o <output> <objects> -L/path/to1 -L/path/to2 -lLIB -lLIB2
```

**Question: How to get the following variables from CMAKE?**

- Libraries directories flags (ex:  `-L/path/to1 -L/path/to2`)
- Libraries link flags (ex: `-lLIB -lLIB2`)

I've read stuff concerning RPATH but it seems to concern shared libraries only. Am I right?

Thanks for advance.
I do appreciate.

Comment: Despite the linking line problems, having multiple symbols doesn't seem a nice thing. Have you considered refactoring the common part of LIB1 and LIB2 into a unique library which is a dependency for both?

Comment: This us definitely what I think! I award your answer since it was, according to me the right one (i méandres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that policy [CMP0003](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#policy%3aCMP0003) may be what you need.

To use it add the following line near the beginning of your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
CMAKE_POLICY( SET CMP0003 OLD )
```

Another possibility is to directly set the dependencies and search path, however it's not the cleanest way. Assuming you libraries are called `liba.a` and `libb.a`, then:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${paths_to_search_for} )
TARGET_ADD_EXECUTABLE(X ${some_sources} )
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(X LIB1 LIB2)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(X a b )
```

Note that in this case `a` and `b` are not cmake targets, therefore a little machinery is needed to correctly set the dependencies.

Comment: I've searched in CMAKE documentation and found the same as you. I tested it before I posted this message. However, either I don't use it correctly, or it does nothing, since link command line produced by cmake is exactly the same, with and without the CMP0003 policy (either OLD or NEW!).

Comment: I confirm this cannot make the job in my case since all libraries are built by the same cmake project. As CMAKE documentation says in CMP0003 policy description: _When all items on the link line have known paths CMake does not check this policy so it has no effect_.

Comment: Policies are not feature toggles. http://www.cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=cd4fa896b . Please don't do this and please don't recommend anyone else do it either.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the design of CMake is that it links with full paths. Why is that a problem?

Toggling the behavior with the policy is not the correct approach.

http://www.cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=cd4fa896b

Answer (score -1):

I think [CMP0003](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0003.html) is used to switch on/off the function of adding searching path automatically as described in the official document

> Libraries linked via full path no longer produce linker search paths.

rather than about replacing the path name with `-l`.

When linking a library, if the library is a target CMake known, CMake always replaces related `-L` and `-l` options with the library's path name. This may not be a problem for linking static libraries. But for a executable to link a shared library, it's may be a problem. Then I found a hacking method, code like below, to solve the problem linking a shread library using `-L` and `-l' rather than absolute path.

```
# Find out the link.txt      
set(LINK_TXT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${ToLinkLib}/CMakeFiles/${ToLinkLIb}.dir/link.txt")

# Add the searching path into link command
add_custom_command(TARGET ${YourTarget} PRE_BUILD
  COMMAND sed ARGS -ie "\"s;[[:blank:]]-l; -L${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH} -l;\"" ${LINK_TXT}
  DEPENDS ${LINK_TXT}
  COMMENT "Hacking CMake: edit __link.txt__ to use -l instead of path to link internal library ...")

# NOTE: Dont't missing the `-l'. 
target_link_libraries(${YourTarget} -l${ToLinkLib})
```

Of course, this is just a hacking so may not be working well with all versions of CMake.

---

**UPDATED**: *why linking a shared library may be a problem?*

When I run a executable cross compiled for android, which linking a shared library built by the same CMake scripts, I've encounter a problem of linking failed. After I used the above hacking method to get a new version, I can run my executable with a command like below

```
 $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./the_exe opts
```